# Linux permissions/write protection despite ownership and permissions being okay

Tags: apache, ubuntu, permissions, apache2, chmod

#### Issue description

Files in a directory seem to be write protected somehow on an Ubuntu box running Apache2 as a web server.

- When I try to edit files in SSH have to do so as root `sudo vi`.
- Sometimes, when PHP tries to write to a file on the server with `file_put_contents()`, I get a permission denied error on the file in the PHP log.

#### Troubleshooting thus far

First, I checked the permissions on files and directories in the directory in question `/var/www/foo` (where `foo` is the root web directory of _one of the sites on the server) `stat -c "%a %n" *`

Pretty much everything is set to 755 right now, recursively

```
775 cgi-bin
775 core.24135
775 gulpfile.js
775 index.php
775 material
775 media
775 node_modules
775 package-lock.json
775 package.json
775 readme.html
775 readme.md
664 sitemap.xml
755 views
775 wp-activate.php
775 wp-admin
775 wp-blog-header.php
775 wp-comments-post.php
775 wp-config-sample.php
775 wp-config.php
775 wp-cron.php
775 wp-includes
775 wp-links-opml.php
775 wp-load.php
775 wp-login.php
775 wp-mail.php
775 wp-settings.php
775 wp-signup.php
775 wp-trackback.php
775 xmlrpc.php
```

When I use PHP to exec `whoami` I get the Apache default user, `www-data`. Since I want this user and myself to write to the directory, I created a new group and gave it ownership of the directory in question, recursively:

```
sudo groupadd wwwusers
sudo gpasswd -a apache wwwusers 
sudo gpasswd -a fooweb wwwusers 
sudo gpasswd -a www-data wwwusers
sudo chown -R www-data:wwwusers /var/www/foo
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/foo
```

Still, PHP has this issue of *permission denied* to the file I'm writing to, and I need to sudo just to edit in SSH.

Any ideas on what else could be wrong?

Comment: what are the permissions of the parent directory, and who owns it?

Comment: The `www` parent directory is owned by root, however `www/foo` is owned by `fooweb` (me) of group `wwwusers`. Both directories are set to 755.

Comment: can you try changing user of `www` ?

Comment: What version of PHP do you use and if you use an older one, is `safe_mode` enabled? `safe_mode` would force the owners of both files (the script itself and the file you try to write) to be the same.

Comment: PHP 7.1.15. You were correct, `safe_mode` was `on`. Good thinking, thanks.